# Getting partiular element values

Tags: xml, vbscript, ixmldomdocument, ixmldomelement

I need to parse a xmlobject and extract from the nodes two values I am able to get two values from those trees. I am stuck on how to traverse down into the node in the loop to grab a value that then will determine if I can grab a second value.

This is in VBS and is being used as an extension in an already functioning program. Have been looking up here and Microsoft documentation but am having trouble getting good information from them for VBS in particular.

Example XML

```
<Detail>
 <StandardLine>
  <Stan>
   <Type>A</Type>
   <Code>1234</Code>
   <Value>sdg</Value>
  </Stan>
 </StandardLine>
 <StandardLine>
  <Stan>
   <Type>C</Type>
   <Code>122234</Code>
   <Value>sdsdgg</Value>
   <Cate>Thiere</Cate>
  </Stan>
 </StandardLine>
 <StandardLine>
  <Stan>
   <Type>1</Type>
   <Code>7336</Code>
   <Value>this one</Value>
   <Stone>diamond</Stone>
  </Stan>
 </StandardLine>
</Detail>
```

```
Dim xmlDoc, nodes, strQuery, objNode
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
'This is inputing the xml as a string from a previous bit of code
xmlDoc.loadXML(XMLOut)

strQuery = "//Detail/StandardLine"
Set nodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes(strQuery)

'Check to see if this xmlDoc has any of the desired SL nodes
If nodes.length = 0 Then
    msgbox "There are no SLine nodes",,"The checker"
    exit function
End If  

'Will only get this far if there is a SLine node
msgbox "Before Nodes" & vbCrLf & nodes.length,,"Pre loop"

' Will go through each SLinenodes
For Each objNode in nodes
    msgbox "I am in the loop!",,"The box...in the loop"

'Here down is what I want to do but am not able to get it to work
        'Need to to process the SLine node
    Type = objNode.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Stan/Type").text

    If Type = 1 Then
       Code = objNode.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Stan/Code").text
    End if

'Will be functions here later to use the variable Code

        msgbox "Number is: " & Code,,"Thereas the number?"
Next
msgbox "After Nodes",,"Post loop"
```

I want to extract from the above XML the value in the element  if the value of the element  is 1.

Edit: fixed a misplaced '/' in the example xml

Comment: There's a problem with the Cate tag in your XML, you have the / outside the <>

Answer (score 1):

I think your XPath to get the Type and Code was wrong. Try the following:

```
Private Sub Parse(p_sXML)
    Dim xmldoc
    Dim objNodes
    Dim objNode
    Dim sQuery
    Dim sType
    Dim sCode

    Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

    xmldoc.Async = False

    ' This is inputing the xml as a string from a previous bit of code
    xmldoc.loadXML p_sXML

    sQuery = "//Detail/StandardLine"
    Set objNodes = xmldoc.documentElement.selectNodes(sQuery)

    ' Check to see if this xmlDoc has any of the desired SL nodes
    If objNodes.length = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no SLine nodes", , "The checker"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Will go through each nodes
    For Each objNode In objNodes

        ' Get Type element
        sType = objNode.selectSingleNode("Stan/Type").Text

        If sType = "1" Then
           sCode = objNode.selectSingleNode("Stan/Code").Text
        End If

        ' Will be functions here later to use the variable Code

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by gathering the nodes I need with the

`xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes(strQuery)`

Then looping over those with a for each loop. For that I created an additional function that I passed `objNode.xml` to and created an additional temporary xmlDOM and then found if the line I needed was in there and if so pulled it out.

```
Function ProcessXML(strXMl)
    Dim xmlDoc,strQT, strQC,type,code, ty
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.Async = "False"
    xmlDoc.loadXML(strXML)

    strQT = "//StandardLine/Stan/Type"
    strQC = "//StandardLine/Stan/Code"

    set ty = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode(strQT)

    if not(ty is nothing) then
       type = ty.text
    else
       type = -1
    end if

    if type = 1 then
       code = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode(strQC).text
    else
       Code = -1
    end if

    ProcessXML = Code
End Function

Dim xmlDoc, nodes, strQuery, objNode
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
'This is inputing the xml as a string from a previous bit of code
xmlDoc.loadXML(XMLOut)

strQuery = "//Detail/StandardLine"
Set nodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes(strQuery)

'Check to see if this xmlDoc has any of the desired SL nodes
If nodes.length = 0 Then
    msgbox "There are no SLine nodes",,"The checker"
    exit function
End If  

'Will only get this far if there is a SLine node
msgbox "Before Nodes" & vbCrLf & nodes.length,,"Pre loop"

' Will go through each SLinenodes
For Each objNode in nodes
    Dim Code
    msgbox "I am in the loop!",,"The box...in the loop"

    Code = ProcessXML(objNode.xml)

'Will be functions here later to use the variable Code

        msgbox "Number is: " & Code,,"Thereas the number?"
Next
msgbox "After Nodes",,"Post loop"
```

The problem I was having was before I was trying to use select methods on what was a IXMLDOMElement that are from IXMLDOMDocuments I think. So to get around that I created new IXMLDOMDocuments from the IXMLDOMElements.
This is what I think. Idk if its just me but getting VBS documentation for this was difficult as f. I was getting javascript or c++ code bits from Microsoft documentation and couldn't find a table showing the methods on IXMLDOMElements.